# Security Voters - 500 error

Tags: silex

I'm getting a weird error when I try to inject the access_manager into the voters, as per the symfony doc.

bootstrap.php

```
$app['security.voters'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return array(
        new UserVoter($app['security.access_manager']),
        new IncludeRolesVoter($app['security.access_manager'])
    );
});
```

Voter

```
class UserVoter extends Voter
{
    const VIEW = 'v3.user_view';
    const EDIT = 'v3.user_edit';

    private $decisionManager;

    public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface $decisionManager)
    {
        $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
    }
```

Error

```
[Mon Jul 11 13:57:01.179118 2016] [:error] [pid 1201] [client 10.0.2.2:54292] PHP 256. {closure:/****/bootstrap.php:738-743}() /****/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:126
```

The error happens only when I try to inject the access manager, which is defined before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service [`security.access_manager`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L138) depends on `security.voters`. You have an infinite dependency loop.

Since `security.access_manager` relies on the voters to take its decision, it is a non sense to ask for it inside your own voters.